# PHP form variables, error for mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, database, arrays, variables

Grr.. spent the last hour reworking it and it still won't function!  I keep getting an error:*Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource*.  Any suggestions?  Made updates, still getting the same error.

```
<?    
    //Extract data from form
    if(isset($_POST["editUserName"])){
 $myUserName = mysqli_real_escape_string($myConn, $_POST["editUserName"]);
    }

 if(isset($_POST["updateSubmit"])){ 
  $mySubmit = mysqli_real_escape_string($myConn, $_POST["updateSubmit"]);
    }


    //Verify form was submitted before beginning database interaction
    if(isset($_POST["updateSubmit"]))
    {

    //Create an SQL delete statement to select the desired record
    $mySQLselect = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE userName = '$myUserName'";
    $myRS = mysqli_query($myConn, $mySQLselect) or die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($myConn));
    $myData = mysql_fetch_array($myRS);

    //Create form output for editing
    echo("<form name='frmEdit' id='frmEdit' action='doEdit.php' method='post'>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='hidUserName' id='hidUserName' value='$myUserName'/>");     
    echo("<p>User Name: <input type='text' name='BuserName' id='BuserName' value='$myData[userName]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>Password: <input type='text' name='BuserPass' id='BuserPass' value='$myData[userPass]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>First Name: <input type='text' name='BfirstName' id='BfirstName' value='$myData[userFirst]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>Last Name: <input type='text' name='BlastName' id='BlastName' value='$myData[userLast]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>Address: <input type='text' name='Baddress' id='Baddress' value='$myData[address]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>City: <input type='text' name='Bcity' id='Bcity'value='$myData[city]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>State: <input type='text' name='Bstate' id='Bstate' value='$myData[state]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>Zip: <input type='text' name='Bzip' id='Bzip' value='$myData[zip]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>Email: <input type='text' name='Bemail' id='Bemail'$myData[email]'/></p>");
    echo("<p>Phone: <input type='text' name='Bphone' id='Bphone'$myData[phone]'/></p>");
    echo("<p><input type='submit' name='btnDoEdit' id='btnDoEdit' value='Make Changes'/></p>");
    echo("</form>");
            }   

            ?>
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to make the existing answers meaningless. If you have a new problem post a new question. Reference this one (in it's original form) and explain that it's a new issue.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
$mySQLselect = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE userName = '$myUserName'";
```

On closer inspection

```
mysql_fetch_array($myRS);
```

should beL:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($myRS);
```

You are missing the last closing curly bracket after:

```
echo("Thank you for creating an account.");
```

Comment: Tried that, and while it may be part of the problem, the only error it is coming up with is for the mysql_fetch_array().

Comment: @Jason McCreary  ... thx but missed one thing :) .... @Anna ... look at the updated answer

Comment: Rock on! Getting closer! Who knew an 'i' could cause so much trouble!

Comment: That in particular error.. working on the next.. I'll update the code above.

Comment: @Anna i have updated the answer above. However you should create new questions for new errors :)

Comment: I usually do, I just didn't want to loose the people helping me!  :)

Comment: @Anna you should start accepting some answer to your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
$mySQLselect = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE userName = '.$myUserName.'";
```

There will be dots inserted too, so the query will probably return zero rows. It should be like this:

```
$mySQLselect = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE userName = '".$myUserName."'";
```

Comment: Tried that, and while it may be part of the problem, the only error it is coming up with is for the mysql_fetch_array().

Comment: Yes, that goes together, if the query returns no rows, `mysql_Fetch_array()` throws this error. After you change this, you still get the error?If yes, I would check if the query really fits to the structure of the table.

Comment: I'm guessing this would be easier if I had access to the database?  I don't unfortunately, the joys of homework.

Comment: Well, yes, that would be very helpful. I dont't know, if your current access level will allow you this, but you can do two things: 1. Select structure from catalogs (information_schema table) 2. Install your own phpMyAdmin

Comment: That's incorrect—at least with `mysqli_fetch_array()`, it returns null if the query results in 0 rows. It only errors if it's passed an invalid MySQLi_Result. The likely problem here is that `mysql_fetch_array()` (rather than `mysqli_*`) is being used with a MySQLi_Result.

Comment: Eek, this is my last assignment, it shouldn't be this hard!  :oP  I'm going to do my best to get it as close as possible, and hope the problem is on the database end, not mine!